# UserControl doesn't show the data

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls

I can't see the uc, well i can see it but it's clean, it's not null cause it show empty uc objects (the correct number of records that are in the db)
But it happens only using the uc cause if i use simple data-binding without uc i can see every records. I've alredy done a breakpoint to see if for some reason the data passed with the dependency property was null, but there are every information in the object, simply it can't pass the data to the uc xaml.

Alredy tried without the uc and it works

UC XAML

```
<Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button x:Name="elementoButton">
                <Image x:Name="elementoImage" Width="64" Height="64"/>
            </Button>
            <TextBlock x:Name="ipTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="nomeTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

UC C#

```
public Classes.Elementi elementi
        {
            get { return (Classes.Elementi)GetValue(elementiProperty); }
            set { SetValue(elementiProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for elementi.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty elementiProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("elementi", typeof(Classes.Elementi), typeof(ElementoControl), new PropertyMetadata(new Classes.Elementi { IndirizzoIP = "0.0.0.0", Nome = "Undefined", Image = "/Control Panel 2.0;component/img/default.png" }, SetElemento));



        private static void SetElemento(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ElementoControl elementoControl = new ElementoControl();
            if (elementoControl != null)
            {
            elementoControl.ipTextBlock.Text = (e.NewValue as Classes.Elementi).IndirizzoIP;
            elementoControl.nomeTextBlock.Text = (e.NewValue as Classes.Elementi).Nome;

            #region SetImage
            if ((e.NewValue as Classes.Elementi).Categoria == "Uruk")
            {
                elementoControl.elementoImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri((e.NewValue as Classes.Elementi).Image, UriKind.Relative));
            }
            else if ((e.NewValue as Classes.Elementi).Categoria == "Server")
            {
                elementoControl.elementoImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri((e.NewValue as Classes.Elementi).Image, UriKind.Relative));
            }
            else if ((e.NewValue as Classes.Elementi).Categoria == "Router")
            {
                elementoControl.elementoImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri((e.NewValue as Classes.Elementi).Image, UriKind.Relative));
            }
            else if ((e.NewValue as Classes.Elementi).Categoria == "Pannelli Solari")
            {
                elementoControl.elementoImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri((e.NewValue as Classes.Elementi).Image, UriKind.Relative));
            }
            else if ((e.NewValue as Classes.Elementi).Categoria == "EasyCapture")
            {
                elementoControl.elementoImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri((e.NewValue as Classes.Elementi).Image, UriKind.Relative));
            }
            else if ((e.NewValue as Classes.Elementi).Categoria == "Computer")
            {
                elementoControl.elementoImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri((e.NewValue as Classes.Elementi).Image, UriKind.Relative));
            }
            else if ((e.NewValue as Classes.Elementi).Categoria == "Internet")
            {
                elementoControl.elementoImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri((e.NewValue as Classes.Elementi).Image, UriKind.Relative));
            }
            else if ((e.NewValue as Classes.Elementi).Categoria == "Stampante")
            {
                elementoControl.elementoImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri((e.NewValue as Classes.Elementi).Image, UriKind.Relative));
            }
            else if ((e.NewValue as Classes.Elementi).Categoria == "UPS")
            {
                elementoControl.elementoImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri((e.NewValue as Classes.Elementi).Image, UriKind.Relative));
            }
            #endregion

            #region IsPingable
            if (IsPingable((e.NewValue as Classes.Elementi).IndirizzoIP))
            {
                elementoControl.elementoButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGreen);
            }
            else
            {
                elementoControl.elementoButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkRed);
            }
            #endregion
            }
            else
               MessageBox.Show("usercontrol nullo");
        }
```

MainWindow XAML

```
<StackPanel>
                <ListView x:Name="elementiListView" Background="DodgerBlue">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <uc:ElementoControl elementi="{Binding}"/>
                            <!--<StackPanel>
                                <Button x:Name="elementoButton">
                                    <Image x:Name="imageButton" Source="{Binding Image}" Width="64" Height="64"></Image>
                                </Button>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nome}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding IndirizzoIP}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </StackPanel>-->
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
```

MainWindow C#

```
private void ReadDatabase()
        {
            List<Classes.Elementi> elementi = new List<Classes.Elementi>();
            using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(App.ElementiDB()))
            {
                connection.CreateTable<Classes.Elementi>();
                elementi = connection.Table<Classes.Elementi>().ToList();
            }
            if (elementi != null)
            {
                    elementiListView.ItemsSource = elementi;
            }
        }
```

In the MainWindow XAML you can see that i've tried without the uc, and without it it works perfectly but i need to use the uc, i expect that either using the uc i can see the same thing that without it

Comment: 1) Put a breakpoint on `elementiListView.ItemsSource = elementi;`: Hover the mouse over `elementi`; does it have any items? 2) Put a breakpoint on the first line of `SetElemento()`: Is it ever called? If it is, step through it (F10) and see what happens line by line. To put a breakpoint in the code, click the mouse on the desired line, and press the `F9` key on the keyboard.

Comment: SetElemento is called and the elementi list is fullfilled with the data in the db, i've already tried to see if it's a problem with the list but it's not, i don't know what do anymore :(

Comment: So you step through SetElemento and everything happens as you expect? Did you confirm all of this in the debugger? You should at least be seeing the buttons in the listview.

Comment: Exactly except of that when i call the uc from the listview it doesn’t fill the texblock and the image but it show them empty, but they are the exact Numbers of object that i want , i think it’s only a problem with the uc when i fill the texblocks and the image with the source and the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: `DependencyObject d` is a reference to the `ElementoControl` whose `elementi` property was just set. But you ignore it. Instead, you create a new one, set properties on it, and throw the new one away. Naturally, the real control shows no sign of having its properties set, because you never touched them.

```
private static void SetElemento(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ElementoControl elementoControl = new ElementoControl();

    //  Why are you checking to see if this is null? You just created it. 
    if (elementoControl != null)
    {
```

Do this instead:

```
private static void SetElemento(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //  If anybody calls this method with a reference to something other than 
    //  ElementoControl, that's a bug and an exception should be thrown. 
    if (!(d is ElementoControl))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("d must be ElementoControl");
    }

    ElementoControl elementoControl = d as ElementoControl;

    //  This should be done mostly in XAML as well, but I don't have time at the 
    //  moment. I would give ElementoControl a boolean readonly dependency property 
    //  called IsPingable. I would set that property here, and in the XAML I would 
    //  give the button a Style with a DataTrigger that set the Button's background 
    //  color according to the value of IsPingable. 
    #region IsPingable
    if (IsPingable((e.NewValue as Classes.Elementi).IndirizzoIP))
    {
        elementoControl.elementoButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGreen);
    }
    else
    {
        elementoControl.elementoButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkRed);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Second: Note that I omitted most of the above method. That's because you should be binding viewmodel properties in XAML. Note also that the vast majority of the above method was a long, long series of if/else branches all of which did the exact same thing. You don't need to decide sixteen different ways to do the same thing anyway. Just do it.

But the real takeaway here is that your UserControl "inherits" its DataContext from its parent, the DataTemplate in this case. For that reason, all those bindings that worked in the original DataTemplate will necessarily work identically in the UserControl (unless you break things by explicitly setting the UserControl's DataContext to something crazy, but from what I can see in your question, you didn't do that (if you did, don't)). UserControls are designed to work this way.

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="elementoButton">
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Width="64" Height="64"/>
        </Button>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding IndirizzoIP}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nome}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the errors but i'm a noob and so i'm trying to learn.
You were much usefull and i learn a lot by what you answer me.
I really thank you, obv it works now

Comment: My pleasure, no need for an apology.